# How do I make my logo go towards the left and my nav bar icons in the middle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

Could somebody please help me with this problem, so basically I want to my logo more towards the left of the navbar and my icons I want to be fixed in the middle with a little bit padding. How do I do this?

[This is it and I want it to look like this (red highlighted parts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pubvJ.png)

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div align="left">
<a href="/"><img width='200' height='50' src='Icons/logo.png' /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">whatshot</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">search</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">person_outline</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    .navbar__link {
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

please answer if you know how to fix, thanks :D!

please someone fix this, please.

edit the code if you have the fix and just write directly bottom to this fixed.

[UPDATE] The logo got fixed but the icons still haven't gone to middle the image link should show how the icons be fixed, thank you everyone who has helped thus far!

[UPDATE] (FIXED)

Comment: this problem has nothing to do with Python. You need CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Does anyone know the problem please help lol

Comment: If you could fix that would be great :D!

Comment: I'm specialist of Python, not CSS, nor JS. I came here only because you added tag `python`.

Comment: No no I was asking the new people who are viewing this at the moment.

Comment: BTW: standard advice: put all in one code so other people could easily copy/paste it to one file and open in browser and use it for test. It is impossible to resolve your problem without seeing it in browser and without having real code which people could change in browser or using portals like https://codepen.io/. Eventually you could add link to your code on codepen so people could test it.

Comment: Okay I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making the div side by side, you can use float instead of align as below.

```
<div style="float: left;">
  <a href="/"><img width='200' height='50' src='Icons/logo.png' /></a>
</div>
```

and if require some padding for logo and the nav.

```
<div style="float: left; padding-right: 10px;">
  <a href="/"><img width='200' height='50' src='Icons/logo.png' /></a>
</div>
```

Edit:
Adding this inline style justify-content: center; should fix it.

```
<div class="navbar" style="justify-content: center;">
  <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
    <span class="material-icons">whatshot</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
    <span class="material-icons">search</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
    <span class="material-icons">person_outline</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**P.S.** Your .navbar css is not read due to the order of linking stylesheet. The bootstrap css will overwrite your customize .navbar css.

Comment: Thank you, but there is one thing missing I need the icons to not be spaced out they look like this currently, I will show it in the question because I can't post it here.

Comment: The logo worked where I wanted it to go but the icons never went to the middle :(. I added a image tho the red pen tells where I want the icons to go. Thanks for the help with the logo tho!

Comment: Which means that you want the logo, and icons at the middle of the bar which is the red highlighted area.

Comment: I’m happy to help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try using flex:

`Html`

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="/"><img width='200' height='50' src='Icons/logo.png' /></a>
    </div>
    
    /* Added class to div*/
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">whatshot</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">search</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="navbar__link">
        <span class="material-icons">person_outline</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
</body
```

`Css`

```
// you don't need to add class to a tag, it can be selected by following way
.navbar > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  // make the header take all space of body
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;

  // make navbar take all space that remains after the logo
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;

  // make the navbar move left side else it will not be in complete middlle
  transform: translate(-100px);
}
```

Comment: @wellcoolname you had many other css property first time I saw your question, first remove those and use what I have given. Once it starts working keep adding new properties. Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hc1ye0zs/

Comment: Yeah I tried and still put it in and the icons don't want to go the middle :(.